# How to expan a block on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Recently, I started my project and faced a small problem.
I have a list of notes, notes are the `div` blocks with code:

```
<div id="note" class="well">
    <p id="caption" class="text-center">%Caption</p>
    <hr id="devider">
    <p id="content">%Content</p>
</div>
```

View on page:

[image]

Now, when I click on this note, nothing happens. I want to make the next feature: in the ordinary state note has only a short part of content, but when I click on a certain note it increases its size and shows all its content.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Where is your JavaScript code..

Comment: Now I don't have some js code, becouse I haven't idea how can I realize it. Illumination of notes realized using :hover css pseudo-selector.

Comment: Without using JavaScript how you can add click event..

Comment: This was actually the question, and Osama below answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) function to do that

```js
$('#note').on('click', function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '200%'
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="note" class="well">
  <p id="caption" class="text-center">%Caption</p>
  <hr id="devider">
  <p id="content">%Content</p>
</div>
```